# Multiple dependent API calls inside React provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript

During local development I get `Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.` in my app when refreshing.

I believe it's because I am doing two calls in my provider. First to get an ID, and then using the ID to do another call.

How can I make my provider work if it has to wait for the first call?

```js
export const VehicleProvider = ({
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<unknown>): JSX.Element => {
  const { data: vehiclesData, loading: vehiclesLoading, refetch } = useQuery(VehicleDocument);

  const { data: chargeSettingsData, loading: chargeSettingsLoading } = useQuery(GetChargeSettingsDocument, {
    variables: {
      input: { vehicleId: vehiclesData.id }, // <-- vehiclesData is undefined during first render
    },
  });

  if (vehiclesLoading || chargeSettingsLoading) {
    return <Loader size="FULLSCREEN" />;
  }

 
  return (
    <VehicleProviderContext.Provider
      value={{
        vehicle,
        chargeSettings,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </VehicleProviderContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useVehicle = (): VehicleProviderContext => {
  const context = useContext(VehicleProviderContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(`useVehicle must be used within a VehicleProvider`);
  }
  return context;
};
```

*I stripped down my provider to make it easier to post here.*

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this file? Usually you get this when you conditionally call a hook or return early before all hooks have run. It's recommended to activate ESLint rule `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Dang, this linter rule had lots of suggestions. I'll look around to see if its used incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Used `vehiclesLoading` to check if `vehiclesData` has returned any data

```
export const VehicleProvider = ({
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<unknown>): JSX.Element => {
  const { data: vehiclesData, loading: vehiclesLoading, refetch } = useQuery(VehicleDocument);

  const { data: chargeSettingsData, loading: chargeSettingsLoading } = useQuery(GetChargeSettingsDocument, {
    variables: {
      input: { vehicleId: !vehiclesLoading ? vehiclesData.id : ""}, // used vehiclesLoading to check if vehiclesData has returned any data
    },
  });

  if (vehiclesLoading || chargeSettingsLoading) {
    return <Loader size="FULLSCREEN" />;
  }

 
  return (
    <VehicleProviderContext.Provider
      value={{
        vehicle,
        chargeSettings,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </VehicleProviderContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useVehicle = (): VehicleProviderContext => {
  const context = useContext(VehicleProviderContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(`useVehicle must be used within a VehicleProvider`);
  }
  return context;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Arkellys I fixed it. I installed a linter and found out that this was not used in the right place. I moved somethings around and suddenly it worked, maybe it wasn't at the top of the component ‍♂️